# Apache Camel - Camel reconnectDelay and maximumReconnectAttempts not working

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I have Quartz Cron job that runs on some schedule and i am using Camel Consumer, Producer template to pickup some files from FTP site and copy it local file system. When using reconnectDelay=60000 and maximumReconnectAttempts=3,throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true with FTP consumer it doesn't try to reconnect, i get null for exchange and consumer stops. Also i am not able to get handle of the exception so that i can have my own logic of retries.

Code snippet

```
public class ScheduleProcessorJob extends QuartzJobBean { 


        @Autowired 
        private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate; 

        @Autowired 
        private ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate; 

protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobContext) 
                        throws JobExecutionException { 

consumerTemplate.start();
```

/* 
Sample srcEndpoint "ftp://batch.com:10021//inbox?delete=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&binary=true&connectTimeout=30000&maximumReconnectAttempts=3&reconnectDelay=60000&passiveMode=true&password=xxxx&readLock=changed&username=xxxxxx&flatten=true&recursive=false"
*/

```
                // loop to get all the files in the remote site 
                while (true) { 
                    Exchange remoteExchange = consumerTemplate.receive(srcEndPoint.toString(), 5000); 

                    if (remoteExchange == null) { 
                        break; 
                    } 


                Exchange postExchange = producerTemplate.send(destEndPoint.toString(),remoteExchange); 

                                /* In case on error 
                                 * 
                                 */ 
                                if(null != postExchange.getException()){ 

                                        throw postExchange.getException(); 

                                } 
                        } 

                } catch (Exception ex){ 
                        LOGGER.error("Error Picking up from Customer ",ex); 
                }finally{ 
                        try { 
                                consumerTemplate.stop(); 
                        } catch (Exception ex) { 
                                LOGGER.error("Error Stopping Consumer template ",ex); 
                        } 
                } 
}
```